# How to customize font size on OSM maps?

Tags: openstreetmap, printing

I saw that with openlayers 3 it's feasible to customize fonts on particular maps elements starting from a GeoJSON list.
Is there a way to customize all labels returned from OSM web site? 
What I want to achieve is printinting a map on big tourist sign (a0 or a1) with readable labels.

I also looked into QGIS but it's not really straightforward to achieve my goal...

Answer (score 4):

A typical tile server returns just images ([tiles](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tiles)). There is no way to change the font style because all labels are directly contained in the images. Unless you decide to render your own tiles [via a tile server](https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/) or one of the [other rendering options](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Rendering).

Also see this related questions on https://help.openstreetmap.org:

- [How to increase font size when viewing OSM?](https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/29621/how-to-increase-font-size-when-viewing-osm)
- [Providers with Font Control?](https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/25613/providers-with-font-control)
- [Font size and adding scale to map](https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/8467/font-size-and-adding-scale-to-map)

Comment: This is an incredibly bad design flaw. Still upvoted for giving info, thanks.

Comment: No, this is not a design flaw. First, OSM is raw data. You can put any renderer you like on top of it. So there are almost no limitations. Second, most of the software around OSM is developed by volunteers. Raster tile servers are the easiest solution and work quite well in most scenarios, from desktop to mobile. Creating more sophisticated solutions is perfectly possible, but time-consuming. Yet, there *are* other solutions available, i.e. [vector tiles](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Vector_tiles). Feel free to use them instead if you want.

Comment: Alternatively, completely drop labels from your standard layer and introduce additional layers just for your labels. This allows you to change the font size by just switching between your labeling layers while preserving the benefits of raster tiles. This requires some more work for your setup, though.

Comment: Maybe this venue is intended for some kind of professionals, but I'm just using an Android app that uses OSM, and I need the fonts bigger. I don't know what a tile server is and I have no intention of running one. I just needed bigger fonts. I ended up simply using something else, unfortunately. Still, thanks for the info, I appreciate it.

Comment: Maybe a tile server with high-resolution tiles (aka retina tiles) would be an option.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into vector tile rendering. That allows for font and symbology changes on the user side.

Unfortunately, OSM is not yet ready for that format (except on Android).